# Getting the value checked from database

Tags: php, html, yii

```
public function actionEditmul($id)
{
         $sql1="SELECT * FROM category_product INNER JOIN category ON category_product.cat_id=category.cat_id WHERE category_product.product_id=$id"; 
         $editcat=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql1)->queryAll();              
         $cat=Category::find()->all(); 
         return $this->render('editmul',['category'=>$cat,'editcat'=>$editcat]);
}
```

and in the html form is:

```
                 <?php foreach ($editcat as $edit): ?>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $edit['cat_id'];?>" ><?php echo $edit['category'];?><br>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>  

                 <?php foreach ($category as $categories): ?>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo $categories->cat_id;?>"><?php echo $categories->category;?><br>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>   
                 <br>
```

With the first loop, i get the values of all the categories checked. and with the second loop, i get the values of all the categories also checked from first. what I want is not to get that values of checked categories in the second loop. Hope you understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php echo checked from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674147/php-echo-checked-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can store the IDS from first loop into array display only those which are not found in array in second loop.

Just like this,

```
<?php $arrayofcategories=array(); ?>
<?php foreach ($editcat as $edit): ?>
    <?php $arrayofcategories[]=$edit['cat_id']; ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $edit['cat_id'];?>" ><?php echo $edit['category'];?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>  

<?php foreach ($category as $categories): ?>
    <?php if(!in_array($categories->cat_id,$arrayofcategories)) { ?>
          <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo $categories->cat_id;?>"><?php echo $categories->category;?><br>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In above code we're saving IDs of category in `$arrayofcategories` and checking (in second loop) if they are already found in first loop, Display only if they're not found.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
<?php 
$editCategory = array();
foreach ($editcat as $edit):
$editCategory = $edit['cat_id'];
 ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $edit['cat_id'];?>" ><?php echo $edit['category'];?><br>
 <?php endforeach; ?>  

 <?php foreach ($category as $categories): ?>
     <?php if (!in_array($categories->cat_id, $editCategory)): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="<?php echo $categories->cat_id;?>"><?php echo $categories->category;?><br>
     <?php endif: ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>   
 <br>
```